# css 'content' feature not showing

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons (each has a rotated div inside to create a triangle on bottom and top of page)

```
<button id="arrow-up">
    <div id="rotate-up"></div>
</button>
<button id="arrow-down">
    <div id="rotate-down"></div>
</button>
```

css

```
#arrow-down, #arrow-up { 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 80px; height: 55px;
}

#rotate-down, #rotate-up {
  border:none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center left;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#rotate-down {
  border-bottom:none;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

#rotate-up {
  border-top:none;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I want to add a black chevron pointing up/down in each button. I wanted to use css

```
content: "/...";
```

to avoid adding any extra divs, to keep it simple, but I can't get it to show on my buttons despite where I put it (I tested it with just a letter).

Comment: you have to use it on :after :before may be

Comment: ? I don't have any before or after elements. Can I not use them in regular css

Comment: you have to add it in css

Comment: What do you mean by "regular CSS"? Using before and after doesn't make it less regular

Comment: I apologize, I meant regular as in not adding psuedo elements. just to the div itself, but as pointed out it has to be applied to :before and :after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content property is exclusive to the ::after (:after) and ::before (:before) selectors.

```
#yourElement:before {
    content: "your content";
}
```

Comment: also, not only to `::before` and `::after` but to `:before` and `:after`

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Here you go

Comment: Oh ok, so I have to add a pseudo element or another div with it inside regardless